# Создание android устройства из qt creator

Tags: qtcreator, android-emulator

Не могу создать android устройство из qt creator. Установлены sdk, ndk, jdk, openssl, нужные API android. При создании устройств из Android Studio нет никаких проблем. QtCreator видит созданные в студии устройства и нормально с ними работает. Никаких ошибок или всплывающих предупреждений не появляется. ОС win10.
[image: Окно создания android устройства в QtCreator. Nexus в листе найденных девайсов был создан из avd менеджера андроид студии.]

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась заданием системной переменной JAVA_HOME